# Setting DMLOptions in an update

Tags: apex, update, duplicate-management

I am currently trying to bypass a `DMLException` thrown by a duplicate rule in an update event just like I bypass it in an insert events, that is by setting the `DMLOptions.DuplicateRuleHeader.allowSave` to true, but it doesn't appear to work.

Even though I have seen that the `Database.update` method does not have a signature which takes a `DMLOptions` instance, I did see that you can set the options in the record with the method `setOptions`. Nonetheless, it does not work.

**Is there any way to bypass the exception in update events, or is it impossible?**

Here is the snippet which I was testing, if it helps to give insight:

```
@IsTest
static void testUpdateContactToDuplicate() {
    TriggerManager.allTriggersDisabled = true;

    Contact record = new Contact(LastName = 'García', Email = 'unicorn@animals.com');
    Contact futureDuplicate = new Contact(LastName = 'Martín', Email = 'shrimp@animal.com');
    insert new List<Contact> {record, futureDuplicate };

    TriggerManager.allTriggersDisabled = false;

    Test.startTest();
    futureDuplicate.AlternativeEmailAddress1__c = 'unicorn@animals.com';
    futureDuplicate.setOptions(getAllowSaveOptions());
    update futureDuplicate;
    Test.stopTest();

    List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id, EmailSetId__c FROM Contact];
    System.assertEquals(2, contacts.size());
}

private static Database.DMLOptions getAllowSaveOptions() {
    Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions();
    dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.AllowSave = true;
    return dml;
}
```

Comment: I think you should do Database.update(listOfContacts, getAllowSaveOptions()); instead of update futureDuplicate; where listOfContacts contains just the one Contact you want to save.

Comment: Oh god. I'm *·$% blind... When I checked the docs I saw that insert had the Database.update(List, DmlOptions) method, but I thought that update didn't, even tho it did surprise me. Thanks for making me double check that @SanderdeJong rofl

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error was pretty silly actually. I didn't see in the docs that a `Database.update` which accepted DmlOptions existed and since my IDE currently doesn't hightlight it as viable, I overlooked it.

The solution is as obvious as the following:

```
Test.startTest();
futureDuplicate.AlternativeEmailAddress1__c = 'unicorn@animals.com';
Database.update(futureDuplicate, getAllowSaveOptions());
Test.stopTest();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an extra option in DuplicateRuleHeader to make saving duplicate availabe for current runing user. You have to set it as true to make it work.

```
private static Database.DMLOptions getAllowSaveOptions() {
    Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions();
    dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.AllowSave = true;
    dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.runAsCurrentUser = true;//IMP
    return dml;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't help bypass the validation rule. Feel free to implement a similar setup and try, but the DMLException is still thrown even if I add the option `runAsCurrentUser`.

Comment: Is the field made unique via Unique Field constraint? or there validation is standard Duplicate Matching rule?

If its due to unique field constraint it won't work.

Comment: The field isn't marked as unique. I just have a duplicate rule which marks records as duplicates if they have the same field value.